# MS bot not working on Skype for Business

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I have registered an MS bot on over Skype for business channel, the bot was searchable and responding for few days but no I am getting below error in "Bot Channel registration">channels> issues

> "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound".

On SFB I get error

> "Error happened in Skype for Business service when reaching bot service".

Bot is hosted over azure in web API working and fine in Web channel, whereas with SFB its not hitting the API endpoint.

Every time I send a message from skype for businesss, I get the same error on bot channel registration.

Environment is a hybrid of Lync 2010 and Skype for business online and after registration bot was searchable and responding to users on SFB online.

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: Whats is your app id?

Comment: Hello  @JasonSowers  I am into the same issue and whatever I tried as a message endpoint Sfb Did not hit to endpoint but WebChannel works fine. Could you help me resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For my situation I realized that if I dont change **messaging endpoint** area everything goes well.I mean I was adding Microsoft App Id to my endpoint like `https://myendpoint/{{MicrosoftAppId}}` after bot created .It is because you can have your microsoft app id after you create the bot.What is awkard is that despite messaging endpoint looks an editable area when I change it I am falling into error place where my endpoint is never called[again webchannel works fine , it looks Skype For Business needs some refactoring]. However I found that if I dont change this endpoint url bot works fine for Skype For Business and my endpoint is hit successfully .So keep your messaging endpoint constant and set it only when creating your bot.